# Trying to prove an identity about a product

Tags: induction

I have a product formula that, given a tuple $(a_1, \dots, a_{n-1}, 0)$, computes a dimension (of a vector space) via the following formula:
$$
\mathrm{dimension} = \prod_{i < j} {(a_i + \cdots + a_{j-1})  + j-i \over j-i} \qquad \text{for } 1 \leq i < j \leq n
$$

I am trying to prove that the only tuples that give me a dimension equal to $p^2$ for a fixed prime $p$ are the tuples $\underbrace{((p^2 - 1)\cdot a_1, 0)}_{\text{has length $2$}}$, and $\underbrace{(a_1,0, \dots, 0)}_{\text{has length $p^2$}}$ and $\underbrace{(0,0, \dots,a_{p^2 - 1}, 0)}_{\text{has length $p^2$}}$. I'm inducting on the prime $p$, and for the base case $p = 3$ I have established this, but now I am confused about how to proceed further. Any tips?

Comment: shouldn't you be inducting on $n$?

Comment: @wece I thought that I should induct on $p$ and then perhaps have a "nested" induction on $n$ inside the proof. How can I induct on $n$ but still establish that it is *only* those above tuples that give me the desired dimension?

Comment: I have no idea :D It's just it feels weird to induct on a "fixed $p$".

Comment: The induction feels weird actually. Did you try a case distinction? Something like: Fix a $p$ suppose that you have a solution not of the forms $(a_1,0)$, $(a_1,0,...,0)$ or $(0,...,a_{p^2-1},0)$. Show that it's not a solution. And show that for your given form, what you propose are the only one possible.

Comment: I will go down that route, thanks for your suggestions @wece